# Freezing application when closing the tab - ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

My whole application freezes when I'm closing a opened tab. I have a lots of code but I really have no idea why is this happening?...

Any ideas?

I would post some code but there is nothing specific which could help... -.-

It happens on more computers and tested on all mayor browsers.

It's a simple layout form.

Comment: I think you need share you code.

Comment: I would look for code that gets invoked as a response to events that get fired when the tab is closed.

Comment: Question is very much incomplete...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

verify if you are ot using a duplicated ID in 2 component.

Comment: This was the case... xD Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

What tab are you closing??? Is it a tab panel component. Keep a debugger pointing the listener which is called on the closing event and debug a little.bit.
And what do u mean by freeze??? U need to share something. It's hard to give a guess for
 the questions.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? Is it happening in other browsers? Is a debugger attached?

In my experience IE is "freezing" when there is a lot of layout being built in the page. It's much more sensible than with ExtJS 2.